# How can I tell what events fire from GXT?

Tags: gxt

I cannot seem to find any documentation of what events fire and when in GXT.

The API docs have lists of all the events that could fire (in `Events`). And it describes how to handle events that you catch. But I'm interested in the opposite side, which events are fired when I take a certain action.

I can set some listeners for various different components, or I can use `addListener` with a specific event code to catch individual events. That's spotty, and I seem to be using trial-and-error to guess what I might want to catch.

Is there a way to log all the events that are firing? Or catch all of them so I could look at them in a debugger?

Or is there some documentation I am missing that has the information? Something along the lines of "when you click on a widget, a `ButtonEvent` is fired. `Events.x` is fired on the hover, `Events.y` on the click."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up using brute force: Created a Map of EventType and name, then attach a Listener for each type of event that the component could receive. Then I just set a breakpoint inside the Listener, and I could see what events were received when anything happened.

If it hadn't been throwaway code, I would have cleaned it up into a utility class, not used an anonymous Listener class, etc.

```
    final Map<EventType, String> eventTypeNames = new HashMap<EventType, String>();
    eventTypeNames.put(Events.BeforeExpand, "BeforeExpand");
    eventTypeNames.put(Events.Expand, "Expand");
    ...
    eventTypeNames.put(Events.BeforeStateSave, "BeforeStateSave");
    eventTypeNames.put(Events.StateSave, "StateSave");

    for (EventType eventType : Arrays.asList(
            Events.BeforeExpand,
            Events.Expand,
            ...
            Events.BeforeStateSave,
            Events.StateSave
    )) {
        this.addListener(eventType, new Listener<BaseEvent>() {
            public void handleEvent(final BaseEvent be) {
                String type = eventTypeNames.get(be.getType());
                String ev = be.toString();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Just found another possible solution: http://loianegroner.com/2009/11/ext-js-which-events-are-fired-by-a-component/

Answer (score 12):

Maybe someone will find this useful, I've created utility class for seeing what kind of events are risen. The idea of course was proposed in accepted answer.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.BaseEvent;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.EventType;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.Events;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.Listener;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.Component;

/**
 * Class for debugging purposes. Sometimes it is hard to tell what type of event
 * is invoked and when. During debug process you can just do:
 * 
 * EventUtils.attachDebugListeners(c);
 * EventUtils.attachDebugListeners(c, "NAME");
 * 
 * You'll then get information about events as they are invoked.
 * 
 * List of events copied from {@link Events} class.
 * 
 */
public class EventUtils {

    public static void attachDebugListeners(final Component c) {
        attachDebugListeners(c, null);
    }

    public static void attachDebugListeners(final Component c, final String msg) {
        for (final EventType type : eventTypeNames.keySet()) {
            c.addListener(type, new Listener<BaseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handleEvent(BaseEvent be) {
                    String typeName = eventTypeNames.get(type);
                    if (msg != null)
                        System.out.print(msg + " -> ");
                    System.out.println(typeName);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    final static Map<EventType, String> eventTypeNames = new HashMap<EventType, String>();
    static {
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Activate, "Events.Activate");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Add, "Events.Add");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Adopt, "Events.Adopt");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.AfterEdit, "Events.AfterEdit");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.AfterLayout, "Events.AfterLayout");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.ArrowClick, "Events.ArrowClick");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Attach, "Events.Attach");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.AutoHide, "Events.AutoHide");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.BeforeAdd, "Events.BeforeAdd");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.BeforeAdopt, "Events.BeforeAdopt");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.BeforeBind, "Events.BeforeBind");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.BeforeCancelEdit, "Events.BeforeCancelEdit");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.BeforeChange, "Events.BeforeChange");
        eventTypeNames
                .put(Events.BeforeCheckChange, "Events.BeforeCheckChange");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.BeforeClose, "Events.BeforeClose");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.BeforeCollapse, "Events.BeforeCollapse");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.BeforeComplete, "Events.BeforeComplete");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.BeforeEdit, "Events.BeforeEdit");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.BeforeExpand, "Events.BeforeExpand");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.BeforeHide, "Events.BeforeHide");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.BeforeLayout, "Events.BeforeLayout");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.BeforeOpen, "Events.BeforeOpen");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.BeforeOrphan, "Events.BeforeOrphan");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.BeforeQuery, "Events.BeforeQuery");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.BeforeRemove, "Events.BeforeRemove");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.BeforeRender, "Events.BeforeRender");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.BeforeSelect, "Events.BeforeSelect");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.BeforeShow, "Events.BeforeShow");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.BeforeStartEdit, "Events.BeforeStartEdit");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.BeforeStateRestore,
                "Events.BeforeStateRestore");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.BeforeStateSave, "Events.BeforeStateSave");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.BeforeSubmit, "Events.BeforeSubmit");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Bind, "Events.Bind");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Blur, "Events.Blur");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.BodyScroll, "Events.BodyScroll");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.BrowserEvent, "Events.BrowserEvent");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.CancelEdit, "Events.CancelEdit");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.CellClick, "Events.CellClick");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.CellDoubleClick, "Events.CellDoubleClick");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.CellMouseDown, "Events.CellMouseDown");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.CellMouseUp, "Events.CellMouseUp");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Change, "Events.Change");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.CheckChange, "Events.CheckChange");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.CheckChanged, "Events.CheckChanged");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Clear, "Events.Clear");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Close, "Events.Close");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Collapse, "Events.Collapse");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.ColumnClick, "Events.ColumnClick");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.ColumnResize, "Events.ColumnResize");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Complete, "Events.Complete");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.ContextMenu, "Events.ContextMenu");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Deactivate, "Events.Deactivate");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Detach, "Events.Detach");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Disable, "Events.Disable");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.DoubleClick, "Events.DoubleClick");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.DragCancel, "Events.DragCancel");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.DragEnd, "Events.DragEnd");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.DragEnter, "Events.DragEnter");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.DragFail, "Events.DragFail");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.DragLeave, "Events.DragLeave");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.DragMove, "Events.DragMove");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.DragStart, "Events.DragStart");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Drop, "Events.Drop");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.EffectCancel, "Events.EffectCancel");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.EffectComplete, "Events.EffectComplete");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.EffectStart, "Events.EffectStart");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Enable, "Events.Enable");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Exception, "Events.Exception");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Expand, "Events.Expand");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Focus, "Events.Focus");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.HeaderChange, "Events.HeaderChange");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.HeaderClick, "Events.HeaderClick");
        eventTypeNames
                .put(Events.HeaderContextMenu, "Events.HeaderContextMenu");
        eventTypeNames
                .put(Events.HeaderDoubleClick, "Events.HeaderDoubleClick");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.HeaderMouseDown, "Events.HeaderMouseDown");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.HiddenChange, "Events.HiddenChange");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Hide, "Events.Hide");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Invalid, "Events.Invalid");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.KeyDown, "Events.KeyDown");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.KeyPress, "Events.KeyPress");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.KeyUp, "Events.KeyUp");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.LiveGridViewUpdate,
                "Events.LiveGridViewUpdate");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Maximize, "Events.Maximize");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.MenuHide, "Events.MenuHide");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.MenuShow, "Events.MenuShow");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Minimize, "Events.Minimize");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Move, "Events.Move");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.OnBlur, "Events.OnBlur");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.OnChange, "Events.OnChange");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.OnClick, "Events.OnClick");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.OnContextMenu, "Events.OnContextMenu");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.OnDoubleClick, "Events.OnDoubleClick");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.OnError, "Events.OnError");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.OnFocus, "Events.OnFocus");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.OnKeyDown, "Events.OnKeyDown");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.OnKeyPress, "Events.OnKeyPress");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.OnKeyUp, "Events.OnKeyUp");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.OnLoad, "Events.OnLoad");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.OnLoseCapture, "Events.OnLoseCapture");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.OnMouseDown, "Events.OnMouseDown");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.OnMouseMove, "Events.OnMouseMove");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.OnMouseOut, "Events.OnMouseOut");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.OnMouseOver, "Events.OnMouseOver");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.OnMouseUp, "Events.OnMouseUp");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.OnMouseWheel, "Events.OnMouseWheel");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.OnScroll, "Events.OnScroll");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Open, "Events.Open");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Orphan, "Events.Orphan");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Ready, "Events.Ready");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Refresh, "Events.Refresh");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Register, "Events.Register");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Remove, "Events.Remove");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Render, "Events.Render");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Resize, "Events.Resize");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.ResizeEnd, "Events.ResizeEnd");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.ResizeStart, "Events.ResizeStart");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Restore, "Events.Restore");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.RowClick, "Events.RowClick");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.RowDoubleClick, "Events.RowDoubleClick");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.RowMouseDown, "Events.RowMouseDown");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.RowMouseUp, "Events.RowMouseUp");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.RowUpdated, "Events.RowUpdated");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Scroll, "Events.Scroll");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Select, "Events.Select");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.SelectionChange, "Events.SelectionChange");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Show, "Events.Show");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.SortChange, "Events.SortChange");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.SpecialKey, "Events.SpecialKey");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.StartEdit, "Events.StartEdit");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.StateChange, "Events.StateChange");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.StateRestore, "Events.StateRestore");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.StateSave, "Events.StateSave");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Submit, "Events.Submit");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Toggle, "Events.Toggle");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.TriggerClick, "Events.TriggerClick");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.TwinTriggerClick, "Events.TwinTriggerClick");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.UnBind, "Events.UnBind");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Unregister, "Events.Unregister");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Update, "Events.Update");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.Valid, "Events.Valid");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.ValidateDrop, "Events.ValidateDrop");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.ValidateEdit, "Events.ValidateEdit");
        eventTypeNames.put(Events.ViewReady, "Events.ViewReady");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The API docs for the various widgets describe what events will fire and when they will fire. For an example, let's say we wanted take an action any time a user chooses a new `TabItem` in a `TabPanel`.

`TabPanel`'s API documentation (located at http://extjs.com/deploy/gxtdocs/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/TabPanel.html) shows several events; we're interested in `Select`:

> Select : TabPanelEvent(container, item)
>
> Fires after a item is selected.
>
> - container : this
> - item : the item that was selected

So, to capture the event (which it appears you understand, but I will include for completeness' sake) the process is to add a listener to the `TabPanel`, watching specifically for the `Events.Select` event:

```
tp.addListener(Events.Select, new Listener<TabPanelEvent>(){
  public void handleEvent(TabPanelEvent be)
  {
    MessageBox.alert("Test", be.item.getText(), null);
  }
});
```

Note that many events have a property called `doit` which you may set to false to cancel the event.

A complete code listing:

```
package edu.fresno.client;

import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.Events;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.Listener;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.TabPanelEvent;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.ContentPanel;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.MessageBox;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.TabItem;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.TabPanel;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.layout.FitLayout;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

public class GWTSandbox implements EntryPoint {
  public void onModuleLoad() {

      TabPanel tp = new TabPanel();

      TabItem ti1 = new TabItem("TabItem1");
      TabItem ti2 = new TabItem("TabItem2");

      tp.add(ti1);
      tp.add(ti2);

      tp.addListener(Events.Select, new Listener<TabPanelEvent>(){
            public void handleEvent(TabPanelEvent be)
            {
                MessageBox.alert("Test", be.item.getText(), null);
            }
      });


      ContentPanel panel = new ContentPanel();
      panel.setLayout(new FitLayout());
      panel.add(tp);
      RootPanel.get().add(panel);

  }
}
```

Comment: This is the opposite side of my question. I'm not trying to handle the events that are fired, I'm looking to find out what events fire when some action takes place.

Answer (score 3):

You could add following code for the constructor:

```
    ContentPanel  panel =new ContentPanel(){
      public boolean fireEvent(EventType type) {
          System.out.println(type.getEventCode());
          return super.fireEvent(type);
      }
      public boolean fireEvent(EventType eventType, BaseEvent be) {
          System.out.println(eventType.getEventCode());
          return super.fireEvent(eventType, be);
      }
      public boolean fireEvent(EventType type, ComponentEvent ce) {
          System.out.println(type.getEventCode());
          return super.fireEvent(type, ce);
      }
    };
```

then it will print any event this component can receive.